# XML Serialization VS XML Parsing

Tags: xml-parsing, xml-serialization

What is the difference between XML Serialization and XML Parsing? When should we use each one?

Answer (score 17):

Parsing is, generally speaking, the processing of an input stream into meaningful data structures; in the XML context, parsing is the process of reading a sequence of characters conforming to the grammar and other constraints of the XML spec into whatever internal representation of XML your program uses.

Serialization is the opposite process:  processing the internal data structures of a program (in this context, your internal representation of an XML document) and creating a character sequence (typically written to an output stream) that conforms to the angle-bracket syntax of the spec.

Use a parser to read XML from a character stream into data structures; use a serializer to write data structures out into a character stream.

Comment: So your saying "parsing" is the same as "de-serialization"?

Comment: I believe that some people use the term "de-serialize" with the meaning "parse", yes.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about XML, but here's what I know about serialization and parsing.

parsing - reading data (parse-in) from storage, and writing data (parse-out) to storage… *"such as a text file"*

serializing - (serialize) translating data into a readable format, and (de-serialize) translate that format back to data… *"i.e. you want to translate a struct into readable content, stream that content across a network, and translate it back into code."*

here's a new one…

marshalling - (marshall and unmarshall) similar to serialize, except marshalling is used to translate data into a different format… *"i.e. you want to translate a stream of bytes into an 32 bit structure (one byte to four bytes)"*

Answer (score 0):

## in easy terms (for beginners)

### TL;DR

XML parsing (or XML deserialization) ==> **input**: valid XML, **output**: data structures

XML serialization ==> **input**: data structures, **output**: valid XML

### XML parsing (a.k.a XML de-serialization)

You take a **.xml file** (example.xml) as **input** to process it with your programming language of choise, so that your programm can do something usefull with the data in that file. Your programm will transform the information from the file into data structures that your programming language can deal with (i.e. lists, arrays, objects, etc.).

### XML serialization

Your programm (in any programming language), transforms information represented as data structures (lists, arrays, objects, etc.) into a valid XML **output** which can be saved into a file or tranmitted to another programm.

NOTE: Technically the input (when we are takling about parsing) and the output (when we are talking about serialization) does not have to be a file. As said in the more professional answer above it can be any input/output stream, too. And files don't have to have .xml extension, they can have any file extension which represents a valid XML format (i.e. .svg is also a XML based format). The key to understanding is, that when we do **XML parsing** we have **valid XML** on the **input** side and data structures on the output side, and when we do **XML serialization** we have data structures on the input side and **valid XML** on the **output** side.

To give an example from the Python world: you can use buildin packages (like [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)) or third party libraries (like [lxml](https://github.com/lxml/lxml) (recommended) or [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)) to do both - parse (deserialize) or create (serialize) XML data.